# How to handle error in sparkjava port binding

Tags: exception, spark-java

I am using sparkjava as an embedded REST server. I have made the port number user configurable, however I want to handle the case where the user has specified a port that is already in use.

The [error handling](http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html#error-handling) section of the documentation only deals with handling routes.

Is there any way to deal with errors that occur when port() is called with a port that is already in use or otherwise invalid?

My current inelegant solution is to check with a server socket before start the class that uses Spark:

```
    try {
        ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(prefs.getListenPort());

        socket.close();

        MyListener listener = new MyListener(sightingQueue, prefs.getListenPort());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // port is not valid
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From my testing, `port()` doesn't throw any exception when called on an already-open port. It just terminates the program. So I guess your method is the way to go, couldn't find any inherent method.

Answer (score 0):

With Spark 2.6.0 you can specify an InitExceptionHandler:

```
initExceptionHandler((e) -> System.out.println("Uh-oh"));
```

There is a release candidate that you can test out:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0.RC0</version>
</dependency>`
```